# How do you get a colorByPoint appearance in Highcharts without coloring all the bars in a group the same color?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to use the `colorByPoint` option as this is more or less what I want, however I have a dual bar graph with two bars per section and I want to color them each a different color based on the series colors.

[image]

When I add the following Highcharts snippet, the bars are styled the way I want. But ultimately I want each section to have its own color scheme. (light purple, dark purple, light blue, dark blue etc.):

```
plotOptions: {
     series: {
        dataLabels: {
             enabled: true,
             format: '{point.label}'
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' km'
        },
        pointPadding: 0,
        groupPadding: 0.1,
        borderWidth: 0,
        colorByPoint: false       // Switch this to true in the jsFiddle
    },
}
```

If you switch `colorByPoint` to true, the colors alternate and progress the way I want, but suddenly both bars in each group are colored the same color.

[image]

How do I use the `colorByPoint` while maintaining that each POINT remains a different color (you'd think it would do this by default).

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u59176h4/31/)

Comment: The `colorByPoint` sets each point's color by the index of the point to the index of the `colors` array you provided. This is why the points are the same. The code is doing exactly as you instructed it to. How to get a different color for each index can be done via some extra code (like a function to return the color for a given series.

Comment: @wergeld Highchart's definition of a `point` is "The Point object is the JavaScript representation of each data point." Considering that each bar is it's own data point isn't this functioning counter to expectation?

Comment: But your plot options are for the `series` so it is plotting each point in the series as a different color. All options under `plotOptions.series` are applied to all series.

Comment: @wergeld hmm, that explains the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comment, [colorByPoint](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.bar.colorByPoint) works per series, so it won't work with the global color arrays. However, you can define colors array per series just as colorByPoint works. Then you can split the initial array and assign them to series.

```
var colors = ['#CDAED1', '#82368C', '#94B8D2', '#2a71a5', '#ED561B', '#DDDF00', '#24CBE5', '#64E572', '#FF9655', 'orange'];

var splitColors = [
    [],
    []
  ];

colors.forEach((color, i) => {
  splitColors[i % 2].push(color)
});
```

In chart config:

```
series: [{
  colors: splitColors[0]
}, {
  colors: splitColors[1]
}]
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/u59176h4/33/